# Php logical expression and objects

Tags: php, object, logic

here is something weird to me.

Code 1:

```
if($city = Cities::find_by_id($city_id)) {
  var_dump($city);
}
```

This returns: object(Cities)#6 (7) {...}, ordinary

Code 2:

```
if($city = Cities::find_by_id($city_id) && $building = Buildings::find_by_id($building_id)) {
      var_dump($city);
}
```

This returns: bool(true), and I expect result like the one before

Can someone explain to me what is happening?

Comment: `$var = Object` assigns Object to `$var`, but `$var = Object && Object` assigns the boolean evaluation of `Object && Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that in first case you are just assigning function return value to variable $city

```
$city = Cities::find_by_id($city_id)
```

and result is pretty much what you would expected. For the second case you are doing something different - you are assigning

```
Cities::find_by_id($city_id) && $building = Buildings::find_by_id($building_id)
```

to variable $city which means if Cities::find_by_id and Buildings::find_by_id both return stdObjects there is logical **and** operator applied.

It is something like:

```
$city = (object) && (object)
```

which is pretty much same as

```
$city = true && true
```

You would probably want to do something like that (see extra parentheses):

```
if(($city = Cities::find_by_id($city_id)) && ($building = Buildings::find_by_id($building_id))) {
  var_dump($city);
}
```